# printf always shows 0 processor time as output

Tags: java, c, clock, execution-time

I wanted to compare two different ways of testing odd or even and I thought of testing which is faster so I tried using the `clock()` function and `clock_t` variables.

Nothing seemed to work. I searched a lot on the web and modified my code based on answers I found on stackoverflow, but still nothing.

This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdint.h>
clock_t startm, stopm;
#define START if ( (startm = clock()) == -1) {printf("Error calling clock");exit(1);}
#define STOP if ( (stopm = clock()) == -1) {printf("Error calling clock");exit(1);}
#define PRINTTIME printf( "%ju ticks used by the processor.", (uintmax_t)(stopm-startm));
#define COUNT 18446744073709551600
#define STEP COUNT/100

int timetest(void){
    unsigned long long int i = 0, y =0 , x = 76546546545541; // x  = a random big odd number
    clock_t startTime,stopTime;
    printf("\nstarting bitwise method :\n");
    START;
    for(i = 0 ; i < COUNT ; i++){
        if(x&1) y=1;
    }
    STOP;
    printf("\n");
    PRINTTIME;

    y=0;
    printf("\nstarting mul-div method :\n");
    START;  
    for(i = 0; i < COUNT ; i++){     
        if(((x/2)*2) != x ) y=1;
    }
    STOP;
    printf("\n");
    PRINTTIME;
    printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I'm always getting `0 ticks used by the processor.` as the output.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

**edit** :

iv had enough of compiler issues.
created a java version of the above program. gives me answers. though its for the java platform.

```
public class test {
    private final static int count = 500000000;
    private final static long num = 55465465465465L;
    private final static int loops = 25;
    private long runTime;
    private long result;
    private long bitArr[] = new long[loops];
    private long mulDivArr[] = new long[loops];
    private double meanVal;

    private void bitwiser() {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            result = num & 1;
        }
    }

    private void muldiv() {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            result = (num / 2) * 2;
        }
    }

    public test() {
        // run loops and gather info
        for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
            runTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            bitwiser();
            runTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - runTime;
            bitArr[i] = runTime;
            runTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            muldiv();
            runTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - runTime;
            mulDivArr[i] = runTime;
        }
        // calculate stats
        meanVal = stats.mean(bitArr);
        System.out.println("bitwise time : " + meanVal);
        meanVal = stats.mean(mulDivArr);
        System.out.println("muldiv time : " + meanVal);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new test();
    }
}

final class stats {
    private stats() {
        // empty
    }

    public static double mean(long[] a) {
        if (a.length == 0)
            return Double.NaN;
        long sum = sum(a);
        return (double) sum / a.length;
    }

    public static long sum(long[] a) {
        long sum = 0L;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            sum += a[i];
        }
        return sum;
    }

}
```

**output** (in millisecs) :

```
bitwise time : 1109.52
muldiv time : 1108.16
```

on average , bitwise seems to be a tad slower than muldiv.

Comment: Have you printed the actual value of your `clock_t` variables? The spec doesn't guarantee that the processor clock time will be available.

Comment: Did you look at the warnings ?

Comment: @chrylis , i dont know how to print clock_t , so i did this `printf("start : %ju",(uintmax_t)startm);` , however , this gave output as 0.

Comment: @P0W , i didnt get any warnings. im using pelles C

Comment: If you use a smaller value for `COUNT` (so that you can see results more quickly) do you still get `0 ticks ...`? (I tried this and got non-zero values)

Comment: i used 1000 as COUNT , but its still the same.@BurhanAli

Comment: 1000 is too small to register any significant timings, so 0 seems legitimate in that case. I didn't get any results until I went to 1000000 so try out some more numbers.

Comment: no matter what i try , i always get 0.

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
#define COUNT 18446744073709551600
```

will overflow, you must append `ULL` to make the literal have type `unsigned long long`.

Comment: like this ?
`#define COUNT 18446744073709551600ULL` , well this do anything different.

Comment: Indeed. Using gcc I got this warning: `warning: integer constant is so large that it is unsigned`

Comment: @BurhanAli im using pelles C , i didnt get any warnings. something might be wrong here.

Comment: @SomjitNag I don't know pelles-C, but have you enabled all warnings? Compilers don't generate all possible warnings by default. You should check your compiler's docs and see what command line arguments are needed to do that.